# wrong interface orientation or unknown

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

The problem is this:

- I put the simulator in landscape
- I start the app
- The app is unable to detect the correct orientation, always unknown!

I have created a sample project that demonstrates the problem I have.
[Take it here](http://www.mediafire.com/?h1wwmlamjjw)

How can I solve that?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug; just use the interfaceOrientation property of your UIViewController to get the current orientation.  That property is always set at app startup.

I recently wrote a blog post on this issue:

http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=25

Answer (score 2):

It's a simulator bug. report it to Apple: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I agree. If it works fine on a device I would chalk it up as a simulator bug. I noticed a bunch of quirky orientation behaviors in the simulator that were not repeated on the device.

Comment: I cannot test it on the real device because there's no iPad in Europe. Is there something that can be done to circumvent this problem, so I can continue developing this app?

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? Because the answer of @Tyler suggests solution..So I am confused whether I am going wrong or its really a bug.. I do not have iPad and I can't crosscheck it..